# How to get ModelState key / Model property names to match?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have an MVC3 application, I'm using EF4.1 Code First and POCO Classes.

My question involves getting rid of hard-coded "PropertyNames" in my POCO Class and also pre-fixing it with the proper values in ModelState so that the validation message appear properly.

I have in my POCO class a method that looks like this.
You will notice that I am also using the "DataAnnotations.Validator" code to re-use the Data Annotations validation.

```
public class TaxCode : ModelBusinessObjectBase
{
    //...

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Effective Date")]        
    public DateTime EffectiveDate
    {
        get { return _effectiveDate; }
        set { _effectiveDate = value; }
    }    

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Expiry Date")]        
    public DateTime ExpiryDate
    {
        get { return _expiryDate; }
        set { _expiryDate = value; }
    }    

    //...

    public override IEnumerable<ValidationResult> GetValidationResults()
    {
        //---- data annotation validation ----
        ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
        IList<ValidationResult> dataAnnotationValidationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, dataAnnotationValidationResults, true);


        foreach (ValidationResult dataAnnotationValidationResult in dataAnnotationValidationResults)
            yield return new ValidationResult(dataAnnotationValidationResult.ErrorMessage, dataAnnotationValidationResult.MemberNames);

        //---- custom business rule validation ----
        // expiry date must be greater than effective date
        if (ExpiryDate <= EffectiveDate)
        {   
            yield return new ValidationResult("Expiry Date must be after Effective Date", new [] {"EffectiveDate", "ExpiryDate"});
        }

        yield break;
    }
```

In my service layer, I will eventually call something like this:

```
    public bool TryValidate(TaxCode domainObject)
    {
        if (!domainObject.IsValid) 
        {   
            _validationDictionary.AddValidationResults(domainObject.GetValidationResults());
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

And using a "ModelStateWrapper", the code does this:

```
    public virtual void AddValidationResults(IEnumerable<ValidationResult> validationResults)
    {

        foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            _modelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

My  view model is this:

```
public class TaxCodeViewModel : IPersistantBusinessObjectViewModel<TaxCode>
{
    public TaxCodeViewModel()
    {
    }

    public TaxCodeViewModel(TaxCode domainObj)
    {
        this.BusinessObject = domainObj;
    }
}
```

And my View looks a bit like this:

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"               Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TaxCodeViewModel>" %>

   //...

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

        <%:Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Unable to save. Please correct the errors and try again.")%>


        //...

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.BusinessObject.EffectiveDate)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.BusinessObject.EffectiveDate)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BusinessObject.EffectiveDate)%>
        </div>
        <br />  
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.BusinessObject.ExpiryDate)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.BusinessObject.ExpiryDate)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BusinessObject.ExpiryDate)%>
        </div>
        <br />  
        //...
```

My Question are:

1. How do I avoid the hardcoded property name strings "Expiry Date"?
2. Because of the ViewModel, expects the ModelState key to be "BusinessObject.ExpiryDate". How do I, get my properties to match? How do I add a prefix or remove the automatically added prefix?
3. Notice I currently use validationResult.MemberNames.First()). 
   In my case, I only want one message in the validation summary, but I would like to have BOTH properties highlighted. i.e. only one message for ".validation-summary-errors" but both fields highlighted for ".input-validation-error" and ".field-validation-error" elements in the DOM.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding property name in attributes is not bad, except functions,etc.I suggest  you to implement new class inherited from [CompareAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) , so most of above code will gone and your hard coding depency problem will be solved.

For highlighting problem you can use java script, or implement some utily function to check if model has error on some field and returning some css class name. Something like fallowing.

```
 <div class="editor-field <%: Html.HasValidationMessage(model => model.BusinessObject.ExpiryDate)%>">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.BusinessObject.ExpiryDate)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BusinessObject.ExpiryDate)%>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the info... I like the highlighting solution. I'll have to take a look at the "CompareAttribute" to see if I can get that to work.

Comment: I can suggest different solution to highlighting , since my validation performed on server side using ajax call, the returned JSON result contains information about invalid html element and validation message. I can set highlighting using jquery.